# What curve_fit to use in scipy for this dataset?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve to a set of data points:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.log(-b * x) + c
    #return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.array(X)
ydata = np.array(y)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r', label='fit')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data set contains about 50 points. 2 of them could be outliers. I generated two plots of the data and fitted curve: the first one contains the outliers and the other plot excludes the outliers: 
[image]

[image]

However, both curve fits contain many NaN values, which is why the red fitted line is so small. I got values of 1 for each variable in `popt`. I tried both the `log` and `exp` fits as seen in the code above

Are there better curves than exponential or log fits that I can try?

EDIT: definition of func comes before the curve_fit call

Comment: Why did you take the axes out? You should show them and try to keep them the same so the figures are easier to compare. Also, you're defining your function to fit after you invoke the fitting procedure... I recommend you to do it the other way around. For completeness, also provide the full code, including your imports.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at `symfit`: https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit It let's you fit your data to symbolic curves, so no need to choose the apporpriate discretization for `x`.

Comment: even when I define the function before invoking `curve_fit` I get the same problem

Comment: 1. Remove the points where `x` is 0. The logarithm is not defined for these. 2. remove the `-` in `np.log(-b*x)`. Optimization starts with positive parameters so the `-` makes the parameters start in an invalid region.

Comment: There are no points where `x` is 0. The closest x values to 0 are -2000 and 3000. In the first plot, the x axes are for every 10000 incremenets and the y axes are for every 100000 increments

Comment: Probably your problem is, as in many fitting situations, that your starting point for the parameters are too far from the optimum. Second point, have you plotted your functions? They certainly don't look like the data you have. Given the second figure, try something like `a*x/(1+b*x)`. In any case, you might have a hard time because you have a lot of points at the left but few towards the right.